# comments textarea shows up twice - custom wordpress comments form

Tags: wordpress

I've got the following code for a custom comments form:

```
<?php $fields =  array(

  'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

    'author' =>
      '<p class="comment-form-author"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" placeholder="*Please enter your name..." aria-required="true" /></p>',

    'email' =>
      '<p class="comment-form-email"><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="*Please enter your email..."  aria-required="true" /></p>',

    'comment_field' => 
      '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" placeholder="*Please type your message here..." name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',

    )),

    'comment_notes_after' => '',

); ?>   
<div class="comments-form"><?php comment_form($fields); ?></div>
```

However, the textarea shows up twice, the default one with label and my custom one without (see screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLH9c.png). How can I get rid of the default one?

Answer (score 3):

This is now solved. The comment_field is not supposed to be in the 'fields' array as it is a distinct parameter for the comment_form() function. So, it should be:

```
<?php $fields =  array(

  'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

    'author' =>
      '<p class="comment-form-author"><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" placeholder="*Please enter your name..." aria-required="true" /></p>',

    'email' =>
      '<p class="comment-form-email"><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="*Please enter your email..."  aria-required="true" /></p>',

    )),

    'comment_field' => 
      '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" placeholder="*Please type your message here..." name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',

    'comment_notes_after' => '',

); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer, it helped me out. Here is my solution:

```
$fields = array(
            'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label><br /> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
            'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label><br /> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        );

$comments_args = array(
            'fields' => $fields,
            'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label> <br /> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p>',
        );

comment_form($comments_args);
```

I'm aware this is a 3 year old question but it was one of very few results I got regarding this question, so thought I would reply to it in case it helps anyone else.